# ox-gfm package install warning

Tags: org-mode, org-export

When I install ox-gfm package, I got below warning:

```
Leaving directory ‘/Users/root/.emacs.d/elpa/ox-gfm-20170304.1504’

Compiling file /Users/root/.emacs.d/elpa/ox-gfm-20170304.1504/ox-gfm.el at Mon Apr  3 22:11:54 2017
Entering directory ‘/Users/root/.emacs.d/elpa/ox-gfm-20170304.1504/’

Compiling no file at Mon Apr  3 22:11:55 2017
Warning (bytecomp): reference to free variable ‘info’
Warning (bytecomp): org-export-collect-footnote-definitions called with 1
argument, but requires 2
Warning (bytecomp): org-html--anchor called with 4 arguments, but accepts only
0-3
Warning (bytecomp): the function ‘org-export-get-reference’ is not known to be
defined.
```

But sounds like org-export-get-reference will be used in publish code, so when I try to publish org file to md file (refer to [this link](https://vurt.co.uk/post/blogging-with-emacs-and-hugo/)), it will report a error:

```
org-gfm-format-toc: Symbol’s function definition is void: org-export-get-reference
```

So I guess we should not ignore the warning!
Not sure if any other depend package missed!

My emacs version on MacOSX 10.12:

```
GNU Emacs 25.2.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin16.0.0, NS appkit-1504.00 Version 10.12 (Build 16A323)) of 2017-04-03
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you should [upgrade](https://github.com/yjwen/org-reveal/issues/152#issuecomment-146449649) to a newer version of Orgmode.

Call `org-version` and see what you get. If it's something like `8.2`, you should upgrade to `8.3` or higher. See the [Orgmode package repo](http://orgmode.org/elpa.html).

Comment: Yeah, my org version is 8.2, how can I upgrade it to just 8.3? The instruction always upgrade to latest one (9.0.5) but I don't want to use 9.0.5 because it will cause another issue! (params variable is void).

Comment: There's no automatic way to do this AFAIK. See discussion [here](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/14281/10269). You can try using [`el-get`](https://github.com/dimitri/el-get), which I haven't used myself.