# Pinning version of a "core" package

Tags: spacemacs, package, package-repositories

How can I pin a version of "smartparens". I thought If I add this to `dotspacemacs-additional-packages`:

```
(smartparens :location
   (recipe :fetcher github
           :repo "Fuco1/smartparens"
           :commit "f7db43d874ac82e4cdce234cb4e578d37207250a"))
```

it would work, but it doesn't. I've tried it with `:version-regexp`. I tried listing smartparens in `dotspacemacs-excluded-packages`, but it still downloads latest available on MELPA.

Comment: [This](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/14263/how-to-install-a-specific-version-of-package/14281) query may help.